# Information theoretic message authentication code (MAC)

Tags: signature, hmac, mac

Let's $\ a,b\ $ be two (pseudo)random independent values, and $m$ be a message, where $a,b,m \in \mathtt{F}_p$, where $p$ is a large prime number.

---

**Question** 1: Is $\ am+b\ $ an information theoretic MAC?

if yes

**Question** 2: Is there any paper/textbook uses it?

Comment: You need $a \neq 0 \pmod p$.

Comment: This is the single block special case of polynomial MACs. See Poly1305 or GHash.

Comment: If $a,b$ are pseudorandom and not truly random, then it cannot be information theoretic.

Comment: Unless a pair $a, b$ is used for only one message, it can't be informational theoretic (or even practically secure).  And, changing the key for each message isn't a standard property of MACs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just collecting some of the comments, if you make sure that $a$ and $b$ are chosen *uniformly* at random with $a \neq 0 \mod p$, then the given function is a **information-theoretic MAC**, basically because it satisfies the following property:

> If $h_k(m) = am + b$ with $k= (a,b)$ and $\tau$ is the codomain of $h_k$, then for all $m\neq m'$ and $t,t'\in\tau$ we have
>   $$\operatorname{Pr}[h_k(m) = t \ \wedge\ h_k(m') = t'] = \frac{1}{|\tau|^2}$$
>   (probability taken over random choice of $k$)

When a function satisfy this property we say it is a **strongly universal function**, and the main result is that such a function is a $1/|\tau| -$secure MAC, that is, the advantage of an attacker is at most $1/|\tau|$ (notice we can not ask for this advantage to be zero because any adversary can always try to guess a valid tag).

Comment: If I have two messages $m_0, m_1$ and get the MAC values for those two messages $h_k(m_0)$ and $h_k(m_1)$, I can compute the MAC $h_k(m_2)$ for any message $m_2$.  How is this information-theoretic?

Comment: @poncho This is **one-time** information-theoretic. I don't know about any other information-theoretic definition (this definition comes from Katz-Lindell book)

Comment: IMHO, if it doesn't meet the standard definition of a Message Authentication Code, it probably should be called something else; possibly a Universal Hash function...

Comment: @poncho I partially agree with you, but consider for example OTP: it is information-theoretic secure using a *one-time game*, it makes certain sense to involve an analogous scenario for the MAC context (but I am aware that the MAC security definition involves oracle access, which is not the case for EAV-secrecy). However, I'm a beginning on this, so I really do not know.